# I am Having problems with showing dates without hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, date

I have an array of dates that I would like to put in a table (single column) and I am trying to show them without the hour minutes and seconds displaying. I am trying to use toDateString() but it returns it with an error (not a function). Is there a way to display just the dates out of this array;

```js
let old_dates = [new Date(1990, 01, 01),new Date(1960, 01, 02),new Date(1996, 05, 22),new Date(1996, 05, 24),new Date(1996, 07, 24),new Date(1996, 10, 25),new Date(1996, 05, 17),new Date(1996, 02, 09),new Date(1996, 06, 30),new Date(1996, 07, 07),new Date(1996, 02, 14),new Date(1997, 11, 29),new Date(1997, 12, 17),new Date(1997, 10, 02),new Date(1997, 08, 06),new Date(1997, 02, 05),new Date(1998, 06, 15),new Date(1999, 10, 02),new Date(1999, 05, 21),new Date(1999, 02, 06),new Date(1999, 05, 22),new Date(2000, 01, 01),new Date(2000, 06, 09),new Date(2000, 09, 22),new Date(2000, 06, 12),new Date(2001, 04, 25),new Date(2001, 04, 11),new Date(2001, 05, 18),new Date(2002, 05, 07),new Date(2002, 03, 29),new Date(2002, 09, 16),new Date(1999, 05, 21),new Date(1999, 05, 21),new Date(1999, 05, 21),new Date(2002, 05, 21),new Date(2002, 05, 11),new Date(2002, 09, 14),new Date(2002, 04, 10),new Date(2002, 09, 10),new Date(2002, 04, 23),new Date(2002, 10, 09)];
console.log(old_dates);
let new_dates = old_dates.toDateString();
console.log(new_dates);
```

Comment: Don't use leading zeroes in literal integers because JavaScript interprets them as Base 8 (octal) instead of Base 10 (decimal)>

Comment: `old_dates` is an `Array<Date>`, not a `Date`, so there is no `.toDateString()` function.

Comment: @Phil I believe the `.call` part is unnecessary. Also they'll probably want `Array.prototype.join` too.

Comment: Well is there anyway of putting them in an html table through js with just the dates?

Comment: `const new_dates = old_dates.map(d => d.toDateString())`

Comment: @ArthurWellesley That's a different question to what you posted. How would you want the dates displayed in a table? One per row per column? One component per column? Multiple per row? Etc?

Comment: @Dai I am writing this in the first line (that i want to put them in a table). the will be placed in a single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Tip: Don't use leading zeroes in literal integers because JavaScript engines *may* interpret them as Base 8 (octal) instead of Base 10 (decimal).

  - To clarify: Older engines that predate ECMAScript 5 *may* interpret `012` (an octal number literal) as `10` in decimal.
  - ECMAScript 5+ requires numbers with leading-zeroes to be treated as octals *only* if all digits are in the range `0-7`, so a literal `08` or `09` will still be interpreted as `8` and `9` in decimal.
  - When in ECMAScript 5+ `'use strict'`-mode then the engine is required to always parse numbers with leading zeroes as decimals, not octals.
  - Though this does mean that if you have `new Date( 1960, 012, 020 )` in a non-strict context then that will be interpreted as the 16th November 1960 (as Months are 0-based, not 1-based, and `12` in octal is `10` in Decimal, which is the 11th Month: November. Yes, this is confusing.).
- Anyway, `old_dates` is an `Array<Date>`, not a `Date`.

  - So you'll need to call `toDateString()` **for each** member of the array.

You can do that with a `for` loop, a `for-of` loop, or with `Array.prototype.map`, like so:

```
// Using loops:
for( let i = 0; i < old_dates.length; i++ ) {
    const dt = old_dates[i];
    console.log( dt.toDateString() )
}

for( const dt of old_dates ) {
    console.log( dt.toDateString() )
}

// Using Array.prototype.map
const formatted = old_dates.map( dt => dt.toDateString() ).join( ", " );
console.log( formatted );
```

Comment: thank you very much Dai. I will be using the Array.prototype.map method and change the dates to single digits.

Comment: @RobG Thank you for the correction. I've amended my answer.

Comment: you can also use [this](https://momentjs.com/) library for formatting dates.

Comment: Just for reference: [numeric literals](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-literals-numeric-literals).